# Ruby Setting custom User Agent in Ferrum

Tags: ruby, http-headers, user-agent

I am building a scraping tool based on ferrum (CDP tool) and I cannot set properly a new user-agent.
User-agent appears in the headers but is not effective. (I think the default_user_agent is not properly overridden).

```
browser = Ferrum::Browser.new

new_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0)"
headers = {
 "User-Agent" => new_user_agent,
 "default_user_agent" => new_user_agent
}
browser.headers.add(headers)
```

Does anyone has an example of a successful setup ?

Comment: Can you describe more? What means not effective? It is properly set, see this [file and line](https://github.com/rubycdp/ferrum/blob/master/lib/ferrum/headers.rb#L47)

Comment: also it is covered with [tests](https://github.com/rubycdp/ferrum/blob/master/spec/headers_spec.rb)

Answer (score 1):

It is working with:

`browser.headers.set({"User-Agent" => new_user_agent})`

It is possible to pass many headers :

`browser.headers.set({"User-Agent" => new_user_agent, "Accept-Language" => "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"})`